# Use Bisection Search to guess number

Tags: python, search

I'm writing a program that is supposed to guess the user's secret number using bisection search. I feel like I understand the concept of bisection search quite well but my IDE (Canopy) won't let me 'run' the code, which I assume is due to an error or something that it wants me to do before I run it.

```
lowend = 1
highend = 100
guess = 50
choice = 0

print "Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"

while choice != 'c':
    print "Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?"
    print "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.",
    print "Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.",
    choice = raw_input("Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")
    if choice == 'c':
        break
    elif choice == 'h':
            highend = guess
            guess = (highend + lowend)/2
            print 'Is your secret number ' + str(guess) + "?"
            choice = 0
    elif choice == 'l':
            lowend = guess + 1
            guess = (highend + lowend)/2
            print 'Is your secret number ' + str(guess) + "?"
    else:
            print "Sorry, I did not understand your input."
            choice = 0

print 'Your number is: ' + str(guess) + "."
```

I'm not sure if there's something I'm doing wrong, but Canopy's green 'run' button is greyed out. Why does this happen? Does anyone see anything obviously wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not a python dev, but you don't have a main method.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea that doesn't matter in Python

Comment: The first four lines are incorrectly indented; perhaps Canopy prevents you from trying to run code with syntax errors? You can always try running the script in something else (IDLE/command line) to see.

Comment: They're correctly indented in my script. I may have messed this up during an edit (while still trying to debug). I'll update. Thanks

Comment: Works for me in ipython notebook

Comment: Really? Nice! Maybe my IDE is just having issues. I'll try uninstalling and running through the shell first.

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: The question wasn't about the IDE. It just happened to be the answer. But thanks for your help gnat

Comment: The funny part is my bi section search was incorrect. I should have been adding highend and lowend.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get this yet?
I think your initial choice should be a space: choice = " "
Also you need parenthesis on your print statements.
Maybe you don't need the raw_ for your input?
Maybe some rounding or making your answers integers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline 

there to provide quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess u need to ask for an input with the *raw_input* function insted of just printin' those messages, the programm can't find l,h or c to make the comparissons.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Canopy's IDE to solve your problem.

I faced similar problem when the other script went into an infinite loop.